# VPS with multiple domains - /var/www OR /home/$user/public_html?

Tags: linux, apache, cpanel, vps

I'm setting up a VPS for my employer that will handle **multiple** domains for ourselves and our clients. **Do you find it's better to make the documentroot /var/www or /home/$user/public_html?** The VPS is managed by cPanel, which by default sets the documentroot to /home/$user/public_html. Structurally it makes more sense to me to place all production sites in /var/www since they're for PUBLIC access, and maybe use /home/$user/public_html for PRIVATE development(?). But I don't know if there might be any technical / security concerns worth considering. Ideally we would be managing these separate domains under a single cPanel account.

The VPS is provided by Hostgator & runs CentOS. Sorry if this is a n00b question, I'm the only one at work who knows linux :p

Comment: Since cPanel defaults to `/home/$user/public_html/` I'd just do it that way. In reality it doesn't matter, I've got servers here at work set up both ways.

Comment: I guess I had been worried that a domain might get associated with a different cPanel user at some point and make things more difficult to manage. But since we should just be using a single user it probably won't matter. Thanks for advice!